# What is a natural French phrase for 'As if I could find them in just about any shop!'

Tags: expressions, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

Having consulted the online dictionaries, I tried to come up with a French phrase for 'As if I could find them in just about any shop!', but I can't think of an appropriate phrase describing the difficulty in finding some sold-out products which my friend would like to get her hands on. I would like to say a thing like this.

> As if I could find them in just about any shop! I'd like to make her happy, but going all over the city to look for them?!

Answer (score 5):

Although there are probably many more ways to phrase this, I'd suggest the following:

> Comme si je pouvais les trouver au coin de la rue.

I can also think about this one, which has [quite a few hits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=premi%C3%A8re+boutique+venue&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3), and whose meaning is a bit closer to the original sentence:

> Comme si je pouvais les trouver dans la première boutique venue.

Literally, “in the first shop that comes by”.

Comment: As slightly modified version: *Comme si ça se trouvait à tous les coins de rue !*

Comment: Dans n'importe quel coin de rue. Ou dans n'importe quel magasin.

Answer (score 1):

I think *n'importe quel* can be a good translation of *any* which in this context seems important

> Comme si je pouvais en trouver dans n'importe quel magasin !

A more contextualized version

> Comme si je pouvais en trouver n'importe où !

Answer (score 0):

Il existe une expression qui traduit assez bien « going all over the city » (faire le tour de la ville).

> Comme s'il y en avait dans la première boutique venue! J'aimerais assez lui faire plaisir, mais de là à faire le tour de la ville à leur recherche il y a une limite!

suggéré par @Montée de lait - Dans cette phrase on peut supprimer la partie « il y a une limite » et le désagrément exprimé est alors peu intense, ce qui conviendrait possiblement mieux en tant que traduction fidèle. De tout façon cette fin de phrase est seulement typique et on peut en imaginer d'autres pour exprimer une variété d'idées et d'intensités du désagrément.

Comment: Belle réponse. Je laisserais personnellement tomber «il y a une limite».